# Does Ubuntu support the thumb-shift keyboard for Japanese?

Tags: keyboard-layout, japanese

[This](http://museum.ipsj.or.jp/en/computer/word/0006.html) is what I'm referring to.

Can I use such a keyboard design [Ubuntu 12.04.1]?

Answer (score 0):

Both the ibus-anthy and scim-anthy input methods support japanese thumb-shift keyboards, though there may be some customisation required.

You may need to first install japanese language support under **System Settings** -> **language support**, then set the keyboard input method to **ibus** -> **Japanese** -> **anthy**.

Some more information:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ja&fromgroups=#!topic/ibus-user/lnoCRoIEBZk

http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/05/29/japanese-input-on-ubuntu-linux-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/